# Apache "require valid-user" is valid across multiple auth types

Tags: apache-2.4, shibboleth, openid

Our Apache uses both mod_shib_24 (SAML-SP) and mod_auth_openidc (OIDC-RP), which both are connected to a Shibboleth IdP (acts as both SAML-IDP and OIDC-OP).

Furthermore we have 2 protected locations, one protected by SAML, the other one protected by OIDC:

```
  ShibCompatValidUser On

  <Location "/">
    Require shib-session
    AuthType Shibboleth
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
    ShibUseHeaders On
  </Location>


  <Location "/oidctest">
    Require valid-user
    AuthType openid-connect
  </Location>
```

Now comes the confusing part:

If I access anything other than /oidctest/, I have to Login using SAML (mod_shib_24 gets involved, as expected), but after a successful authentication I can also access /oidctest/ without having to authenticate with OIDC.

This also works the other way around. If I access /oidctest/ first (new private window), I have to authenticate using OIDC (mod_auth_openidc gets involved, as expected), and after a successfull auth I can also access all other Locations (other than /oidctest/).

So how does Apache handle valid-user directives? How is a "valid-user" defined in Apache?

Is a user valid for everything once he has logged in, no matter the auth-type, no matter the module, no matter the protocol?

Or is this an unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding from the Shibboleth wiki that the *ShibCompatValidUser On* settings is expressly intended to be compatible with *require valid-user* statements.

> Prior to V2.5.2, and when ShibCompatValidUser is Off (the default),
>   this is equivalent to the shib-session rule above. When the
>   ShibCompatValidUser option is enabled, this rule is implemented
>   compatibly with the rule implemented by Apache itself and requires a
>   non-null REMOTE_USER value be set for the request. This restores the
>   ability to deploy Shibboleth along with other modules and rules. A
>   future version of the SP may remove the "special" definition and such
>   rules should be changed to rely on shib-session.

See https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPhtaccess

To differentiate between modules you could also use tests with **Require env** to look for enviroment variables set by the module. Shibboleth by default sets a **Shib-Session-ID** for example.

See https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeAccess

Comment: this answers the question why the SAML-protected content is working with an OIDC-authenticated user, so there must be something similar in the OIDC module to accept a SAML-authenticated user, right?

Comment: Actually I am confused, do you really use a 2.4 shibboleth module? Because the configuration contains directives from the 2.5 version. In 2.5 you should do a **<requireall>** section with require shib-session and require shib-user to only take shibboleth authenticated users. If you want both providers to authenticate you have to use a **<requireany>** section with nested **<requireall>** sections.